# Update Data frame Column with Reference to Itself

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I have the following data frame. I want to modify the following date's Open_Value column if the previous day has a value > 0 in the Cash_Rebal column. So looking at the DF below I'd like to construct logic like the following:

Open Value = If the previous day's Cash_Rebal column <= 0 then previous day's Close_Value, else prevoious day's Close_Value + Previous days Cash_Rebal.

I tried doing this:

```
df['Open_Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Close_Value'].shift(1) if x['rebal'] <= 0 else x['Close_Value'].shift(1) + x['rebal'].shift(1), axis=1)
```

but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shift'

Existing DF:

```
         Date Name  Open_Flag  Close_Flag  Open_Value  Close_Value  Cash_Rebal
0  2023-03-05  abc          1           0        1000        900.0           0
1  2023-03-05  ext          1           0        1000       1100.0           0
2  2023-03-05  xyz          1           0        1000        970.0           0
3  2023-03-06  abc          0           0         900        720.0           0
4  2023-03-06  ext          0           1        1100       1320.0         660
5  2023-03-06  xyz          0           0         970       1261.0         660
6  2023-03-07  abc          0           0         720        691.2           0
7  2023-03-07  xyz          0           0        1261       1891.5           0
```

Here is my desired dataframe:

```
         Date Name  Open_Flag  Close_Flag  Open_Value  Close_Value  Cash_Rebal
0  2023-03-05  abc          1           0        1000        900.0           0
6  2023-03-05  ext          1           0        1000       1100.0           0
3  2023-03-05  xyz          1           0        1000        970.0           0
1  2023-03-06  abc          0           0         900        720.0           0
7  2023-03-06  ext          0           1        1100       1320.0         660
4  2023-03-06  xyz          0           0         970       1261.0         660
2  2023-03-07  abc          0           0        1380       1324.8           0
5  2023-03-07  xyz          0           0        1921       2881.5           0
```

Comment: When using `apply` on a dataframe, the function in it only receives a single row. Accessing a column of this row results in a single value.

Comment: hmmm... so do you have a recommendation of another way to get the desired output?

Comment: Temporarily add shifted columns of `Close_Value` and `Cash_Rebal`. Then the function in `apply` has access to the previous values through this columns.